How can I get the path of Android internal storage in Dioxus@0.6?
I'm guessing I should use android_activity::AndroidApp::internal_data_path. But how can I access access to AndroidApp in Dioxus?
Crosslinks:

Rust forum
Dioxus Github discussions
Reddit


You can access Downloads folder path using below code,
val downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

Here is the function it will create a file on downloads folder and return the path of the file which is created.
fun getLogFilePath(): String {
    try {
        val downloadsDir =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val file = File(downloadsDir, "logfile.txt")
        file.createNewFile()
        return file.path
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        return "Failed to Creating New Log File"
    }
}

